# Vue App layout for pages with insertion of different blocks on a specific page

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a some vue project:

```
App.vue
layouts 
---- DefaultLayout.vue
views
---- Home.vue
---- About.vue
....
```

**DefaultLayout.vue:**

```
<template>
  <span>
    <div class="change">
      <slot/>
    </div>
    <b-container>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </b-container>
  </span>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "DefaultLayout"
};
</script>
```

**Home.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="change">
      <h1>Default layout</h1>
    </div>
    <h2>Default Layaout > Home</h2>
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'Intro', params: { id: intro }}">intro</router-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import DefaultLayout from "../layouts/DefaultLayout";

export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    DefaultLayout
  }
};
</script>
```

**About.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div class="change">
    <h2>Default Layaout > About</h2>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import DefaultLayout from "../layouts/DefaultLayout";

export default {
  name: "about",
  components: {
    DefaultLayout
  }
};
</script>
```

The point is to make a general layout for the pages (views), but with the ability to change a specific block (`class = "change"`). For home, one content, and for about, another, but the general framework of the pages.

**Now:**

```
<div id="app">
  <span>
    <div class="change"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <div class="change">
          <h1>Default layout</h1>
        </div>
        <h2>Default Layaout &gt; Home</h2>
        <a href="#/" class="router-link-active">intro</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

And it should be (without double `change`):

```
<div id="app">
  <span>
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <div class="change">
          <h1>Default layout</h1>
        </div>
        <h2>Default Layaout &gt; Home</h2>
        <a href="#/" class="router-link-active">intro</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

[**codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-wlgwb?fontsize=14)

**Question:** How to format layout (general template-frame of pages) with `slot` (different inserts in a certain place) for app vue views (pages)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Named views from vue-router : https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html

You would have a view for the part that changes, a default view for the rest.

In your layout:

```
<div class="change">
     <router-view name="title">
</div>
```

Each part would have its own component, for instance `About` and `AboutTitle`.

Then in the router config:

```
routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "DefaultLayout",
    component: DefaultLayout,
    children: [
      {
        path: "about",
        name: "About",
        title: "About",
        components: {
            default: About,
            change: AboutTitle,
        },
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

Alternatively, you can use slots in `DefaultLayout`:

```
<div class="change">
    <slot name="title"></slot>
</div>
<slot></slot>
```

And use `DefaultLayout` directly in your page:

```
<DefaultLayout>
    <template #title><h1>About title</h1></template>
    <h2>About content</h2>
</DefaultLayout>
```

In the route configuration, you would not declare the `DefaultLayout`:

```
routes = [
    {
        path: "/about",
        name: "About",
        title: "About",
        components: {
            default: About,
            change: AboutTitle,
        },
    },
]
```

The second option has a drawback however: the `DefaultLayout` will be recreated when pages change.